# Can't read textfile in java (Android studio)

Tags: java, android, file

I've tried searching for questions like mine, found alot but non of the answers worked for me.
I'm working with Android studio and trying to open a text file from a java class, but no matter what I do or how I'm trying to open it - I'm getting this error:
"... open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

As you can see - I also tried two options: 
1. creating a "File" class (then at the watches window I tried to invoke - "canRead()" function but getting back "false" value. 
2. trying to send the ctor of "FileReader" class the path of my file. 
non of them worked.

thanks alot!

```
    public void fillDatabase(){
    File file = new File("C:\\fillStops.txt");

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + STOPS_TABLE_NAME);
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("C:\\fillStops.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            this.addStop(line);
        }
        fileReader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        String s = e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because your android device doesn't have a `C:\ ` drive...

Comment: omg omg omg... save us...

Comment: Hahaha, funny1.. ;)

It's not windows Dude.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, and place your textfile at the root of your sdcard else change the path for file in the following code.

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");

//Read text from file
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    String aDataRow = "";

        while ((aDataRow = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line+= aDataRow + "\n";
        }

 Log.d(">>>>>", line);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}
```

Hop it will clear the things for you. :)

P.S

Don't forget to add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` permission into your manifest.